# setting cpu affinity for linux kernel, not process

Tags: linux, kernel, affinity

I am having a hard time finding information about how to set cpu affinity for linux kernel (with all of its loaded modules), NOT for a specific process.

This is because I want the kernel to run on CPU 0 all the time to handle I/O stuff, and not do any switches to run on other 3 CPUs because it may pollute L1 and L2 caches.

Thanks in advance.

Nulik

Comment: I believe it may already do this - at least interrupt handlers always seem to run on core 0.

Comment: I read in an article that kernel may run in different cores, and when I checked some source files there were many 'spin-lock' calls, i.e. it locks because the kernel code may be executed in parallel on different CPUs

Comment: @Nulik: System calls made by user threads will cause the kernel to run on many different cores.  That's very different from parallel interrupt handling, though.

Comment: Do not know why the question is closed. Setting affinity has fully **programming** intention. Voted for reopen.

Comment: I don't think this is an off-topic question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kernel work on behalf of processes will always happen on the CPU that makes the request.  You *can* steer interrupts, though.  Look at `/proc/interrupts` to identify the interrupts you want to move (say everything matching `eth0`) and set the affinity by echoing a hexadecimal mask to `/proc/irq/XXX/smp_affinity`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable the other cores via a kernel command-line option.

Not having the kernel run on a core implies that nothing else can run on that core either.  No kernel scheduler and no TLB setup -> no code executing.